# The tags [fitness] and [sport]

Tags: discussion, tags

The [fitness](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fitness) tag is currently used on 7 questions, the [sport](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sport) tag is currently used on 8 questions. Both lack a tag excerpt.

Should these be separate tags? If yes, how do we define them?

Somewhat related, but I guess different enough, is the tag [health](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health), which is currently used on 17 questions.

On [Creating tag synonym: the 5 points rule](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/creating-tag-synonym-the-5-points-rule), the tags "fitness" and "health" were mentioned.

Comment: Ugh. `fitness` could be a synonym to either `sport` or `health` – depending on context. Stand-alone, I'd say it's ambiguous (Fitness = "good health state" || "doing excercises"): "depending on your personal fitness … you might need doing some fitness training".

Comment: Sports usually involve fitness, but not always.  For example, some people consider chess to be a sport.  Fitness sometimes involves sport, but not always.  For example, yoga is not typically considered a sport.